# How to expand $\frac1{2z-z^2}$ about z=1?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to expand $\frac1{2z-z^2}$ about z=1?And naturally,what is the radius of convergence of the series.

I know this is a stupid question but I am just a beginner.

I can see $\frac1{2z-z^2}$=$\frac1{1-(z-1)^2}$.And $\frac1{1-(z-1)^2}$=$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-1)^{2n}$.And the radius of convergence of this series is just 1.So is it the right answer?

Comment: This is not a stupid question. Some people (like me) don't understand it. This was created so that everyone can learn or check their answers

Comment: Your expansion is correct, and the radius of convergence is correct.

Comment: The expansion should have $(z-1)^{2n}$

Comment: Yes,it is a typo,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, but I suggest you use the following more general method to obtain it:

To find the power series around $a$, let $z = a+w$, and substitute to express everything in terms of $w$ so that it is clear what the behaviour of the function is as $w \to 0$.

In this case:

Let $z=1+w$

Then $\frac{1}{2z-z^2} = \frac{1}{ 2(1+w) - (1+w)^2 } = \frac{1}{1-w^2}$

Now it is clear that as $w \to 0$, the limit is $\frac{1}{1}$, which is of course the first order term. To understand this and other expansions better we can subtract the first order approximation to get $\frac{w^2}{1-w^2}$, which clearly approaches $w^2$ asymptotically, so that is the second order term. If you continue you will of course obtain the standard expansion $1+w^2+w^4+w^6+\cdots$.

Comment: Oh and when you learn complex analysis you will see that the power series around a point is valid for any open disk centred at that point on which the original function is complex differentiable, which means that we can immediately identify the radius of convergence to be $1$ since the only poles of the function are at $w = \pm 1$. If you don't want to identify poles you can also get the radius of convergence using the formula $\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$ where $a_n$ is the $n$-th coefficient of the power series.